# How to reduce camera field of view (FOV)?

Tags: optics, camera

If I have a camera with a FOV of, say, 17⁰ deg, how can I limit that FOV to 1x1 deg? I imagine some sort of mask is what I am looking for, but what needs to be considered in designing a solution?

Comment: Would [photo.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Is this in the context of doing an experiment? I don't think we can comment without more details to explain exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a zoom lens? If so, zoom in. If not, you are out of luck.

Your $17^o$ FOV will take a photo of everything in a cone. If you are taking a picture of a brick wall in front of you, that $17^o$ angle will determine how many bricks are in the photo.

If you want a narrower FOV, you want a photo of fewer bricks, just the ones in a $1^o$ cone. That is what a zoom lens will do.

Putting a mask over the lens is like closing down the aperture. It reduces the amount of light, making the photo darker.